# At what points in Forza 3 do you start races in higher positions?

Tags: forza-motorsport-3

Semi-migrated from [SmarterGamer](https://web.archive.org/web/20110202205012/http://smartergamer.com/questions/507/at-what-points-in-forza-3-do-you-start-races-in-higher-positions).

I'm playing through the career mode of Forza Motorsports 3, and now get starting positions ranging from 1-3. When I started the game, I was starting at position 8. (Both of these are assuming an 8-car grid.)

I'm fairly certain this has to do with driver level, but I'm not sure what the progression rate is. It doesn't seem consistent, as depending on the race and the vehicle I choose, I may be anywhere from pole position to position 3 now, and I haven't really paid attention (d-oh) while going through the career.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the highest PI, then:

```
Driver Level 1 - 4 start in 8th
Driver Level 5 - 9 start in 7th
Driver Level 10 - 14 start in 6th
Driver Level 15 - 19 start in 5th
Driver Level 20 - 24 start in 4th
Driver Level 25 - 29 start in 3rd
Driver Level 30 - 34 start in 2nd
Driver Level 35 - 50 start in 1st
```

Comment: What if you don't have the highest PI?

Comment: @John Then you start according to PI ranking. If you are level 50 and have the lowest PI then you start last.